# ipod Touch Second Generation - buttons vanishing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I have an application that was originally created compatible with iOS 2.x. With Xcode not supporting 2.x anymore, I was forced to make it compatible with 3.x.

The app works beautifully on iPhone 3G, 3GS and 4, but some buttons are vanishing on iPod Touches 2nd Gen.

My theory is that these devices are using iOS < 3, so my questions are:

The only thing I did in my project is to set DEPLOYMENT TARGET to iOS 3.

1) Is there anything I have to add in the plist to block 2.x devices?

2) is that possible that these persons were able to download and install the new 3.x release even owning devices that don't support it?

3) UIKit was made required. Do I have to make it leak?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to target devices with OS < 3, you need to set your deployment target to less than 3..(2.2.1 probably?) however i believe in the latest Xcode this is not allowed, so you are basically out of luck on reaching OS < 3.

On a side note: admobs statistics reported almost a year ago that about 98% of iphone/ipod touch users are running atleast iOS 3.0.

Comment: No. I want not to support 2.x. My question is how to block 2.x devices.

Comment: well the app store should do it automatically, i was under the impression you can't even log in the app store under 2.x anymore.

Comment: this is the problem. I suspect that somehow some users with 2.x (not using jailbroken devices - as far as they told me) were able to run this app of mine that in theory is set for 3.x. This is how I was trying to certify that nobody with 2.x will be ever able to run the app.